# "python3": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown." Getting this error while running a dockerfile for a bioinformatics tool

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-3.6, bioinformatics

I am trying to create a dockerfile for my NGS tools.
I am working on a cluster and I had installed miniconda3 locally.

Firstly I created a base dockerfile containing the path of miniconda bin and build it.
After that I created the dockerfile for my tool.

This is what my base docker file looks like:

```
FROM centos:7
ENV PATH="/home/nirmal/new-cluster/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
RUN conda install -y mamba -c conda-forge
RUN conda init bash
RUN echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc
```

And this is what my docker image for the tool looks like:

```
FROM base:latest

RUN echo "source activate mitozEnv" > ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH="/home/nirmal/new-cluster/miniconda/envs/mitozEnv/bin:$PATH"

VOLUME /nfs_master/nirmal/simulated_reads/25K/Hiseq

WORKDIR /nfs_master/nirmal/simulated_reads/25K/Hiseq

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

This is the script that I used:

```
fq1=sim_hiseq_exponential_R1.fastq
fq2=sim_hiseq_exponential_R1.fastq
outprefix=mitoz
time docker run -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD --rm mitoz:latest \
python3 /home/nirmal/tools/MitoZ/version_2.3/release_MitoZ_v2.3/MitoZ.py all \
--genetic_code 2 \
--clade Chordata \
--insert_size 300 \
--thread_number 4 \
--fastq1 $fq1 \
--fastq2 $fq2 \
--outprefix $outprefix \
--fastq_read_length 126 \
1>m.log 2>m.err
```

But when I tried running it with a small test data I got this error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "python3": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You could debug this issue with `docker exec -it YOUR_IMAGE_NAME bash` or `docker exec -it --entrypoint bash YOUR_IMAGE_NAME`. Specifically, look where Python3 is installed and whether you can find that location in the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. I tried that but it keep giving me error: `Error: No such container: base`

Comment: Most paths in Docker don't read a `.bashrc` file, so those "activate" lines don't really do anything.  There's not really anything "in" this Docker image (especially, it doesn't contain any part of your application); can you use Conda without Docker for this task?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I already set the tools using conda and I really need to run docker to get the memory statistics of the tools. So, can you please suggest anyway through which this problem can be solved?

Comment: I'm sorry, should be `docker run -it YOUR_IMAGE_NAME bash` or `docker run -it --entrypoint bash YOUR_IMAGE_NAME`. `exec` is only for already running containers.